# Keycloak 15.0.2: Getting started: WildFly error "Required mechanism 'KEYCLOAK' is not available in mechanisms [..] HttpAuthenticationFactory

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I'm trying to follow the '*Getting Started*' procedure of the latest (15.0.2) Keycloak.

Using the *WildFly 25.0.0.Final*,
updated with *keycloak-oidc-wildfly-adapter-15.0.2*

The WildFly error happens when installing the *app-profile-jee-vanilla* quickstart sample, while running the command
'*mvn clean wildfly:deploy*':

```
19:58:05,514 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."vanilla.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."vanilla.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The required mechanism 'KEYCLOAK' is not available in mechanisms [BASIC, CLIENT_CERT, DIGEST, FORM] from the HttpAuthenticationFactory.
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90) 
...
```

As far as I see the *KEYCLOAK* mechanism is present in the *http-authentication-factory* section of *standalone.xml* config file.
Any idea, why it's *not available* ?

Comment: have the same problem. any success on your side?

Answer (score 2):

According with this [article](https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/blog/securing-wildfly-apps-openid-connect/), to Wildfly 25 it not necessary install any adapder, but the in web.xml the name must be **OIDC** instead **KEYCLOAK**.

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>OIDC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```